# How can I see a list of all of my GitHub comments, including ones on commits (and not using an API)?

Tags: github

What GitHub page and query could I use?

https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions isn't helpful because I can't see the actual message of the comments.

https://github.com/search?q=involves%3A%40me&type=pullrequests doesn't seem to be right, either.

https://github.com/search?q=commenter%3A%40me&type=commits says "The commenter qualifier is not supported when searching commits."

Is https://github.com/search?q=commenter%3A%40me&type=pullrequests&s=updated&o=desc my best option?

Answer (score 1):

> And no using the API

Then... it does not seem supported by [GitHub search syntax](https://github.com/search/advanced) alone.

> I'd further be able to filter to comments from me that have not been responded to.

"Responded to"? That seems unclear, considering the "response" may not always come in the form of a direct reply, and could be part of another conversation in the same thread.

As a simpler alternative, you could try and get the last comment on each issue you have commented on and check if it is yours. If the last comment is yours, it could be seen as not responded to... even though, again, a response might be somewhere else in the thread.

Even if you were to consider the GitHub API, there is no endpoint for getting all comments by a specific user across different repositories.
And there is not a straightforward way to get all comments made by a specific user. You would have to use these endpoints to get comments on individual repositories, issues, pull requests, and commits, then filter them by user. That could potentially involve a very large number of API requests, especially if the user has interacted with many different repositories.

Still, to illustrate the API approach for issues and PR of a given repository:
(Do replace `:username`, `:owner`, `:repo`, and `:token` with your GitHub username, repository owner's username, repository name, and your personal access token respectively)

### `github_unresponded_comments.py`

```py
import requests
import time

username = ':username'   # your GitHub username
owner = ':owner'         # the owner of the repository
repo = ':repo'           # the repository name
token = ':token'         # your GitHub personal access token

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'token {token}',
}

# Get all issues from the repo
response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues', headers=headers)
issues = response.json()

# Get all pull requests from the repo
response = requests.get(f'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls', headers=headers)
pulls = response.json()

# Concatenate issues and pull requests
items = issues + pulls

unresponded_comments = []

# Now check each issue/pull request to see if your comment is the last one
for item in items:
    time.sleep(1)  # to prevent hitting the rate limit
    comments_url = item['comments_url']

    response = requests.get(comments_url, headers=headers)
    comments = response.json()

    if comments:
        # Check if the last comment is from the user
        last_comment = comments[-1]
        if last_comment['user']['login'] == username:
            unresponded_comments.append(last_comment)

# Print all comments that haven't been responded to
for comment in unresponded_comments:
    print(f"Unresponded comment in issue {comment['html_url']}: {comment['body']}")
```

That would check both issues and pull requests in a repository and find the ones where the last comment was made by the specified user.

```bash
cd /path/to/the/directory
python github_unresponded_comments.py
```

But it does not handle [pagination](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/using-pagination-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28) or [rate limits](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/rate-limit/rate-limit?apiVersion=2022-11-28)

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! Re: "there is not a straightforward way to get all comments made by a specific user." Wow, that's disappointing to hear (and a bit surprising). I would have expected that many people would want this feature. I also edited my question to remove the "ideally" part since I agree with you that it was asking for too much (and would probably require AI if it would ever be possible at all).

Comment: @Ryan Hopefully, I am wrong, and your bounty will attract a better answer. And just in case, this answer illustrates the API approach.